# reading an xml file and re-arranging elements based on xsd schema

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have an XML file that is being created by my application. The issue I have is that the elements in the xml file are not in the same sequence as the XSD file (a requirement in order to have the file processed by the vendor).

My XSD file snippet is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Vehicle">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Ford" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="SectionA" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="AX010_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX040_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX050_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX190_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="A080_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX230F_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX230G_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX230GNOTE_1" type="ExplanatoryText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX230H_1" type="Dollar" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX230HNOTE_1" type="ExplanatoryText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                        <xs:element name="AX230J_1" type="ExplanatoryText" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>
```

my xml file snippet is:

```
<SectionA>
   <AX010_1>121</AX010_1>
   <AX050_1>334122</AX050_1>
   <AX090_1>113</AX090_1>
   <AX040_1>334477</AX040_1>
   <AX230H_1>301</AX230H_1>
   <AX230F_1>3651122</AX230F_1>
</SectionA>
```

How can I read through the XML file and re-arrange the elements so they are in the same sequence as the XSD file?

I have looked through similar posts on SO, but I was not able to resolve my issue (prefer using LINQToXML).

Comment: please include the relevant part of your code in your question. How are you creating the xml now? Can you show us?

Answer (score 0):

If serializing to and from a c# class, set the "Order" property on the XmlElementAttribute.  [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will to generate these attributes for you with the `/order` option.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
public string AX010_1 { get; set; }
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
public string AX040_1 { get; set; }
```

Using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer` will then take care of ordering your nodes when you serialize it.